# Property objectMessageAsJsonObject="true" in log42.xml (jsonLayout) doesn't work with netty server (webflux). With tomcat server, it works

Tags: java, spring, logging, netty, log4j2

I am setting my application logs to be painted in JSON format. In the log4j2.xml file, I have the following configuration for my appender:

```
<JsonLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true" includeTimeMillis="true" includeStacktrace="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="true">
</JsonLayout>
```

With the property **objectMessageAsJsonObject = "true"**, I am stating that if an attribute of a printed log is an object, paint it as JSON.

My problem is that it doesn't paint it as json, it paints it as json but in string form:

Example: **(Look at the message attribute)**

```
{"timeMillis":1637633364457,"thread":"reactor-http-epoll-1","level":"DEBUG","loggerName":"es.example.controller.HelloWorldController","message":"{\"name\":\"Josué\"}" ... }
```

I am using **webflux** and the embedded server it uses is netty. I have observed that if I **exclude the netty server** and **include the tomcat server**, the attributes that are objects are correctly painted as JSON.

In the pom.xml I am excluding the spring-boot-starter-logging artifact and adding the spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency, as indicated in all guides.

Anyone know how to get it to work properly with the netty server? Thanks in advance.